# If (interior.north west) is the north west anchor A of a tcolorbox, how can I draw a line from this point to A + (1cm,1cm) (for instance)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

Ok thanks to cfr, I have a much simpler reformulation of my question.

Using an example from the `tcolorbox` doc

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=My Title,
overlay={%
\begin{tcbclipinterior}
\draw[red,line width=1cm] (interior.north west)--(interior.south east);
\draw[red,line width=1cm] (interior.south west)--(interior.north east);
\end{tcbclipinterior}}]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
```

This makes a X in the bg of the box bound to the corners of the box.

But let's say instead of `(interior.north west)`
I want `(interior.north west) + (1cm,1cm)` (meaning a point with a x and a y 1cm higher).

How would I go about it ?

Comment: Welcome! So you don't want to include it as a background image, right? You want to draw that frame around the box? Because you want the proportions of the image to change and not just the size. So you can use the anchors **tcolorbox** provides to do this, I think. Or, if the frame should be around the entire box, you can draw it as a border. But I think you want the first. For example `(interior.north west)` and `(interior.south east)` for the top left and bottom right corners of the body content.

Comment: We need the code for the image you want added to be of much help, I think, and some idea of what is meant to go where in it. Depending on the intended outcome, I wonder if `tcolorbox` is really required here at all and if you would be better off just creating an environment based on the code for the frame. But I'm not really clear what the intended result is.

Comment: Well, the `border` styles can do that: they allow you to add a border around the entire `tcolorbox`, separated by some configurable distance from it.

Comment: Ok I was confused, now I understand a simpler reformulation of my problem and I edited my question to reflect it. Thanks.

So I can draw stuff with (interior.north west) but what if I want a point 1cm higher than that ? Same with any corner of the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `+` and `++` provides a solution to my problem (as I discovered once I searched for tikZ and coordinates, dumb me).

`++` allowing to refer the last point, while `+` does the same but do not update the last point

For instance 
`\draw (interior.north west)+(0,1)--+(1,1)--+(1,0)--cycle`
would draw a square of 1 unit with `(interior.north west)` in the bottom left corner.

Comment: I don't understand, didn't you simply want to lengthen the lines you were drawing?

Comment: My example was just an example. Maybe it would not be 1cm, 1cm, but -3cm, 5cm the next time.

So relative positioning was the answer

Comment: Please make sure your question is clearer next time.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it at the moment, but this should work

```
\draw[shorten <=-1cm, shorten >=-1cm, red, line width=1cm] ...
```

Shorten, as expected, makes the line shorter by the amount specified at the indicated end (`<=` means at the starting point, while `>=` refers to the ending point), but by using a negative amount, it achieves the opposite effect.